# Is this a sensible form iteration pattern for a web form with an unknown number of fields?

Tags: html, php5, codeigniter, form

I'm designing a small intranet-based time-tracking web app that accepts an unknown number of data "rows" which each consist of 7 form fields. Rows can by dynamically added by the browser.

**Can I do better?**

Given this (partial) example POST data:

```
$_POST['project'] =>    
 Array
 (
     [0] => PROJECT_CODE_1
     [1] => PROJECT_CODE_1
 )

$_POST['task']      
 Array
 (
     [0] => 21
     [1] => 4
 )

$_POST['date']      
 Array
 (
     [0] => 2012-07-31
     [1] => 2012-07-31
 )
```

And this iterator:

```
<?php
$insert_values = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['project']); $i++)
{
    $insert_values[] = array(
        'entry_id' => null,
        'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'project_id' => $_POST['project'][$i],
        'task_id' => $_POST['task'][$i],
        'date' => $_POST['date'][$i]
    );
}

$this->db->insert_batch('entries', $insert_values);
?>
```

In general, is this iteration pattern safe and sensible? `POST['project']` is a drop-down, is validated and will always be filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this iteration pattern safe?

Safe for what? Safe for a database? We can't tell you that! There's no code for your database entry function. What you have here is perfectly safe, but that's excluding any type of insert into a database. To safely protect yourself from SQL injection and [other types of security exploits](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets), use [prepared queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), [validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473586/input-sanitization-vs-validation) (sanitize only if needed) incoming data (which includes the username and `$_POST['project']`!), and [encode any output](https://www.php.net/htmlentities).

Without your database function, it's difficult to critique your code. There's not too much that be be done wrong in the snippet provided.